# rsync exclude a folder that's only under a specific folder

Tags: macos, rsync

What I have is this.

```
/home/EverythingElse/files.any
/home/AndroidStudioProjects/Project1/build/files.any
/home/AndroidStudioProjects/Project2/build/files.any
/home/AndroidStudioProjects/Project3/build/files.any
/home/AnotherThing/build/filesToBackup.any
```

I want to use rsync to backup everything EXCEPT files in any build folder under AndroidStudio BUT I want to include the build dir under AnotherThing.

What I'm after is how to wildcard the middle of an exclude string.

UPDATE: I found

```
--exclude AndroidStudioProjects/**/build/**
```

works but leaves the build dir empty. I'd like to not have the build dir as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked it out. The answer is:

```
--exclude AndroidStudioProjects/**/build/
```